# Will in-apps work even though during testing it is in testing mode?

Tags: android, eclipse, sdk

I've made an android app with in-apps. And works in my testing mode (with the fake VISA details). However when I upload it to google play store and download the app again.. it still gives me the fake-Visa details. I've added the product ID in the developer console and all but it still appears as a test account.

Some notes: I've used the same account as the test as to the real app (ie: downloaded from the google store).

If I need to modify (lets say define a product ID in the app where do I do it?) because at the moment I am using android.test.purchased or something.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it myself, what I did was change android.test.purchase to my productID